# authentication conflict between sessions in Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, cookies

I am playing around with [this](https://github.com/tranhungt/okcupidjs) library and I am experiencing an annoying scenario which I believe comes from some sort of conflict in cookies or headers authentication.

When I login to one account everything works great. But then when trying to login to another account, it simply ignore the new data provided and move through the authentication with the **old** data and connecting to the **old** account. No matter if the `email` or the `password` even exist. (Tried also with fake data).

The library doesn't have proper `logout` method which make sense, you dont really need one because when you run it simply using `node` on your machine without any server involved and there is no cookies or any kind of data in memory, everything work great. I can login to as many account as I want.

The problem is when running it on an Express server.

CODE:

```
// api.js

const OKCupid = require("./okc_lib");
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const okc = Promise.promisifyAll(new OKCupid());

async function start(req, res, next) {
  const {
    body: {
      username,
      password
    }
  } = req;

  try {
    await okc.loginAsync(username, password);

    okc.search(
      searchOpt,
      (err, resp, body) => {
        if (err) return console.log({ err });

        const results = body.data;

        // do dsomething with results
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "OK" });
        });
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Something went wrong", error });
  }
}

module.exports = { start };
```

```
// routes.js

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { start, login } = require("../actions/okc");

router.post("/login", login);
router.post("/start", start);

module.exports = router;
```

So when trying first to post to `url/login` it works fine. But when you try to do it again with different `username` and `password` it simply go through and ignore the new data and connect to the old one.

As part of my investigation I looked at the source code of the library and found a method `clearOAuthToken` which clear the token from the header. However it didn't really do anything. So I tried to remove the `jar` initialisation from the `requester` helper and it was the only thing that helped me to move on and login to another account. **BUT** it was only for experimenting and cant be a solution as you do need those cookies for other parts of the library. It was only a proof the problem isn't in the headers but in the cookies.

Any idea how can I "reset" state of server between each call?

Answer (score 1):

"*when trying to login to another account, it simply ignore the new data provided and move through the authentication with the old data and connecting to the old account.*"

As OP mentioned in the comment, this is not an `authorization` header issue, but a cookie issue.

To implement the logout interface, you can manually clear the cookies:

```
OKCupid.prototype.logout = function(){
  request = request.defaults({jar: request.jar()}) // reset the cookie jar
  headers.clearOAuthToken(); // just in case
}
```

Comment: sorry for not mentioning it but I already tried it. it seems that that its not a header issue but a cookies issue. The only thing that "worked" for me is to remove the `jar` initialisation from `Requester` and only then I could login to another account. BUT it's not usable like this because then you can't use the lib because it depends on other cookies in the `jar`, it was simply to test where the issue comes from.

Comment: Can you add this important information in the question?

Comment: added. Sorry for that

Comment: @obiwankenoobi I've updated my answer, please check

Comment: hoe can i set `cookie_jar ` in there or ever use the `request ` instance? they both doesnt exist in this scope. Both created in `Requester.js` and not in `client.js` or it will work with new instance?

Comment: @obiwankenoobi hmmm... I don't understand your question. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: So in `Requester.js` the jar is being set here: `jar: cookie_jar` inside the `Requester` constructor. But in your answer you simply create new `jar` and assign it to a variable. It never went through back to the `Requester` constructor and to the `request` method. How can I set the new `jar` back into the `request` which was created in the constructor back in `Requester.js` ?

Comment: Ah, I understand your question now. My fault. The answer is updated.

Comment: I was the update. Whouldn't it be `this.request  = request.defaults({jar: request.jar()})` because,  where is `request` point to?

Comment: any way it still not working. The system somehow still remember the last request that has being made. It only start to work after couple of minutes. Lets say I am now trying to login with WRONG data, next time I try with GOOD data it wont let me login and say my data is wrong. Just like it remember good login, it remember bad login. It doesnt make any sense..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193453/discussion-between-shaochuancs-and-obiwankenoobi).